# Typescript Async : How can I return data only after all the code has executed

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

I am struggling with returning data only after the code has executed.  The below code retrieves data from indexedDB and returns it to a component. I know this can be achieved using observable or promises but I am struggling with the implementation. Currently the return runs before the above code completes

```
retrieveData() {
    let dbReq = indexedDB.open('myChatDb', 1);
    let db;
    let objectStore;
    let results;
    let transaction;
    let data = new Array();
   dbReq.onsuccess = function (event) {
      db = (event.target as IDBOpenDBRequest).result;
      transaction = db.transaction(["customer-messages"]);
      objectStore = transaction.objectStore('customer-messages');
      results = objectStore.openCursor();
      results.onsuccess = function (event) {
        let cursor = event.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
         data.push(cursor.value);
         cursor.continue();
        } else {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.length + " array length line 36");
        }
      }
      return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a promise to encapsulate the event handlers and then `await` that:

```
function openDb(dbName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let dbReq = indexedDB.open(dbName, 1);

        dbReq.onsuccess = () => resolve(dbReq.result);
        dbReq.onerror = (event) => reject(new Error('Failed to open DB'));
    });
}

function queryObjectStore(objectStore) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let results = objectStore.openCursor();
        let data = [];

        results.onerror => () => reject(new Error('Encountered error querying object store.'));
        results.onsuccess = () => {
            let cursor = event.target.result;
            if (cursor) {
                data.push(cursor.value);
                cursor.continue();
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        };
    });
}        


async retrieveData() {
    const db = await openDd('myChatDb');
    const transaction = db.transaction(["customer-messages"]);
    const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('customer-messages');
    
    return await queryObjectStore(objectStore);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. This looks like a viable solution but I am getting "Property 'transaction' does not exist on type 'unknown'" on db.transaction(["customer-messages"]);

Answer (score -1):

this can be achieved using async await
you just need to make **retrieveData** as a async function and then you need to add await keyword where you are retriving data from database

```
async retrieveData() {
let dbReq = indexedDB.open('myChatDb', 1);
let db;
let objectStore;
let results;
let transaction;
let data = new Array();
await dbReq.onsuccess = function (event) {
  db = (event.target as IDBOpenDBRequest).result;
  transaction = db.transaction(["customer-messages"]);
  objectStore = transaction.objectStore('customer-messages');
  results = objectStore.openCursor();
  results.onsuccess = function (event) {
    let cursor = event.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
     data.push(cursor.value);
     cursor.continue();
    } else {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.length + " array length line 36");
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Hi this wont work, it seems like you cant use await on function expression. Tried it before and it didn't work. Thank you for your input

Comment: then you can try using it on db.transaction.